# How send sms using Cloudhopper SMPP

Tags: java, android, hosting, smpp, cloudhopper

I write an Android application which send a sms to client about your meeting (reminder). Today I can’t use Android SMS Manager because Google’s privacy policy prohibits.

So, I use a library [Cloudhopper SMPP by Fizzed (forked from Twitter)](https://github.com/fizzed/cloudhopper-smpp).
But I can't connect. I do not understand how to do it. And this example is test. I interesting how to connect without test!

What should I do for a direct connection? if possible in more detail and understandably.

Thanks!